# Control what information tracker indexes

Tags: gnome, configuration, search, tracker

I am looking for information on `tracker`, and generally speaking I find it very scarce.

In particular,
**is there any reference describing the possible configuration to set what `tracker` indexes?**

I found [here](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/install-tracker-by-default-in-18-04-lts/1483/4) the following configuration options, but I don't know how/where to use them

```
-- enable-writeback false
-- index-optical-discs false
-- index-on-battery false
-- index-removable-devices false
-- ignored-directories ['core-dumps', 'CVS', 'lost+found', 'po', 'vendor']
-- ignore-stop-words true
-- ignore-numbers true
-- max-words-to-index 1000
-- removable-days-threshold 3 ? (I don't not understand this)
```

*From* 
**[The tracker FAQ](https://gnome.pages.gitlab.gnome.org/tracker/faq/)**:

> **How can I control what Tracker indexes?**
>
> In GNOME, you can use the Search Settings panel to control what
>   Tracker indexes. See [GNOME's documentation](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/unstable/files-search.html.en).
>
> You can control Tracker's configuration directly using dconf-editor or
>   the gsettings CLI tool. The relevant schemas are
>   org.freedesktop.Tracker.Miner.Files and
>   org.freedesktop.Tracker.Extract.

*So I go to...* 
**[GNOME's documentation](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/unstable/files-search.html.en)**:

Customize files search only describes how to control *which* files are indexed, not *what* is indexed.

Answer (score 4):

From the tracker faq:

> You can control Tracker's configuration directly using dconf-editor or
>   the gsettings CLI tool. The relevant schemas are
>   org.freedesktop.Tracker.Miner.Files and
>   org.freedesktop.Tracker.Extract.

You can use `dconf-editor` to find tracker's settings.

1. Open `dconf-editor`.
2. Go to: `org/freedesktop/Tracker/Miner/Files`.
3. Look for `index-recursive-directories`.
4. Add/remove directories you want (don't want) tracker to index.